# Parameter 'IncludeMarkup' in method Presentation.ExportAsFixedFormat2 does not seem to work

Tags: c#, pdf, export, powerpoint, vsto

Product: Microsoft PowerPoint for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13801.20036) 32-bits.

Development environment: VSTO C# addin with Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a C# VSTO Addin with Visual Studio
2. Create a function which uses the ExportAsFixedFormat2 function and set parameter 'IncludeMarkup' to false.

Description of parameter 'IncludeMarkup' is:

> Whether the resulting document should include associated pen marks.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.exportasfixedformat2

For example:

```
string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat2(Path.Combine(filePath, "testExport.pdf"),
                    PpFixedFormatType.ppFixedFormatTypePDF,
                    PpFixedFormatIntent.ppFixedFormatIntentPrint,
                    FrameSlides: MsoTriState.msoTrue,
                    PpPrintHandoutOrder.ppPrintHandoutVerticalFirst,
                    PpPrintOutputType.ppPrintOutputSlides,
                    PrintHiddenSlides: MsoTriState.msoTrue,
                    IncludeMarkup: false);
```

3. Run the program in PowerPoint
4. Create a presentation
5. Add an ink drawing ([Draw ink in presentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeSPU.png))
6. Call the function in your program
7. Inspect the PDF output file

What is the problem?
The problem is that the ink drawing is in the PDF file.

How should it work?
The inkt drawing should not be in the PDF file. Analogous to the builtin functionality of PowerPoint to Export PDF files where you can uncheck 'include ink' option.

[PDF export options in PowerPoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VxsN.png)

Question: Am I right that this is a bug in the PowerPoint API or does the parameter 'IncludeMarkup' have another meaning?

Comment: Not sure but since you used `MsoTriState.msoTrue` for the other parameters did you try `MsoTriState.msoFalse` instead of `false` for `IncludeMarkup`?

Comment: The parametertype of IncludeMarkup is of type boolean and not of type MsoTriState.

Comment: Right my fault advantage if one is able to read the manual :p • Other idea: you mix named parameters (like `FrameSlides: `) with parameters submitted by their position. At least in VBA that is not possible, and it looks like a potential issue to me here too. But if I try to run the same in VBA the markup gets exported too.

Comment: In VBA it is the last parameter of method:
Application.ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat2 "ppttest.pdf", ppFixedFormatTypePDF, , , , , , , , , , , , , , False

The ppttest.pdf file (which is placed next to the presentation.pptm) also contains the ink drawing.